# How to start Server user authentication in PHP and Apache?

Tags: php, apache, authentication

I had a production server which used to authenticate user before granting access. I setup a new machine and copied files from the old server. Now, I can access pages fine, but it does not ask for username and password. When I checked the value of `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` is returns nothing.

Is a way to activate it on the server or I missed any file while copying it from old server ?

Comment: Did you try: http://serverfault.com?

Answer (score 3):

Check the .htaccess file on the old server.  There is probably something like:

```
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "admin"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/path/to/.htpasswd/public_html/admin/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

That's what's doing the authentication, not PHP.

Comment: But I have also copied the .htaccess file. But its still not asking for username and password !

Comment: Did you copy the .htpasswd file as well?  Is the path to the .htpassword the same?